# Kendo UI Mobile how to disable touchmove binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm upgrading to Kendo UI Mobile v2013.1.514 (from v2013.1.319) and everything works great except that it attaches "touchmove" along with preventDefault() for everything inside of my views.

It seems to attach touchmove prior to the first showing of the view.  I could code around it (unbind, then bind, etc...) but it wouldn't be too pretty.

Is there an option I can specify that would make it not attach touchmove in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The touchnmove is handled by the View's Scroller. You can avoid that if you remove it with the [stretch](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/view#configuration-stretch) configuration option or replace it with the native overflow scrolling - with [useNativeScrolling](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/view#configuration-useNativeScrolling). The second option won't remove the scroller where native scrolling is not available e.g. in Android 2.x.

Comment: I tried both, but neither prevent this handler from being added to touchmove:

Comment: function (e) {e.target.tagName.match(/textarea|input/i)||e.preventDefault();}    I check it by using $._data($('#divId')[0], 'events').  And also by attempting to scroll my own home-made scroller...